# Select single row in SQL Server with a condition that selects more than one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

My table that I want to select the data from:

[image]

Code:

```
if exists(select * from MyTable where ActChildID_FK = @actid_fk)    
begin    
    declare @parentid int, @fnname nvarchar(100)    

    select @parentid = ActParentID_FK 
    from MYTabe 
    where ActChildID_FK = @actid_fk    
end
```

The problem is that when the `ActChildID_FK = 300734` it returns 2 values for the `ActParentID_FK`, I need to be able to receive only one value and I do not want to change any of the values in my table.

Comment: *I need to be able to receive only one value* ... which one value?

Answer (score 0):

> Just use `TOP 1` for getting single row. see more details on this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

```
if exists(select * from MyTable where ActChildID_FK = @actid_fk)

begin    
     declare @parentid int,@fnname nvarchar(100)    
     select TOP 1 @parentid = ActParentID_FK from MYTabe where ActChildID_FK = @actid_fk    
end
```

Comment: In reality i want the statement to check in another table if there is only 300734 and 300735 then i want the parent ID to be 300678 , but if there is 300734 and 300735 and 300140, 300141 ... etc then the parent ID should be 300138 . this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are there any conditions to take just 1 out of the 2 results you are getting. If not you could simply use "Top 1"

```
if exists(select * from MyTable where ActChildID_FK = @actid_fk)

begin

declare @parentid int,@fnname nvarchar(100)

select top 1 @parentid = ActParentID_FK from MYTabe where ActChildID_FK = @actid_fk

END
```

Comment: In reality i want the statement to check in another table if there is only 300734 and 300735 then i want the parent ID to be 300678 , but if there is  300734 and 300735 and 300140, 300141 ... etc then the parent ID should be 300138 . this is the problem

Comment: are you saying it is based on the count of the children the parent has? higher the count take that parent?

Comment: @Harvester -- it is not clear what the rule is for selecting a value -- can you give actual inputs and expected results *in your question*